# Findbug immutable date fixes do not work

Tags: java, immutability, encapsulation, getter-setter, findbugs

I have maven findbug plugin version 2.5.4, and in my code it shows me error:

```
.getDateRlpx() may expose internal representation by returning Price.dateRlpx 
.setDateRlpx(Date) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into Price.dateRlpx
```

However in my code I use:

```
public Date getDateRlpx() {
    return DateUtil.immutableDate(dateRlpx);
}

public void setDateRlpx(final Date dateRlpx) {
    this.dateRlpx = DateUtil.immutableDate(dateRlpx);
}
```

And my immutableDate:

```
public static Date immutableDate(final Date sourceDate) {
    if (sourceDate == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new Date(sourceDate.getTime());
}
```

Why does findbug show this error? I created a new Date object. I even tried simple return `new Date(dateRlpx.getTimes())` but it also did not work. I could not find any solution.

Comment: This does not really answer your question (see below), but as additional comment: if you can, consider upgrading to Java 8 (which unlike previous versions _does_ provide immutable Date and Time core classes). While at it, you might want to upgrade your FindBugs plugin as well 3.x has been released many moons ago, with nice new improvements).

Comment: When I try your example, FindBugs works correctly and the warning is not shown. The Maven FindBugs Plugin 2.5.4 uses FindBugs 2.0.3, I tested with FindBugs 2.0.2. So unless it's a bug that was introduced in 2.0.3, it's a problem with your environment. Maybe it's somehow showing you old error messages or something?

Comment: If you can't migrate to Java 8 yet, you can still use JodaTime on which it is based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Thomas was right, it was problem with environment, specificly with running tomcat server from IDEA IDE, it somehow prevented findbug to check fixed source code and instead it checked the one in target directory or in .war i didnt check it for sure. So now it's all work and findbug agree that new Date(date.getTime()) is a solution :)